# Python and SQLAlchemy Printing Database Contents Using For Loop

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to run the program below

```
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

def main():
    flights = db.execute("SELECT origin, destination, duration FROM flights").fetchall()
    for flight in flights:
        print(f"{flight.origin} to {flight.destination}, {flight.duration} minutes.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

but it seems to have this syntax error.

[image]

I already tried installing sqlalchemy again and i dont know if I'm missing something or what i've done wrong since I'm new to python and sql. I've also made sure that the table already exists as seen below.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error has nothing to do with sqlalchemy. As @snakecharmerb suggested, check that you are using a version of Python that supports f-strings.

Answer (score 0):

fixed the problem by running python3 list.py instead of python list.py